# Datatable paging in record count?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatable in jquery. Now I have some issues which I can't figure it out. I have 100 records and I want to do paging on the basis of these records but not want to fill the data in datatable.

The actual  idea is to reduce and load. I have 10000000 records in table and if I bind all records in datatable it will took allot of time so the idea is to first bind 10 records and make pages when user click on second page I bind more 10 records and so on.

Any one can help me out.

Thanks

Comment: You are probably looking for the datatables server side processing feature. It allows you to shift the processing load to the server and the database backend.

Comment: @James Massey can you please refer me an example. I am not able to figure it out

Comment: http://datatables.net/manual/server-side

Comment: @James Massey there is no way I can make paging on the basis of recordset and on every page click I bind 10 records.